# How to use xQuery

Tags: xslt, xquery

I have an xsl file which I am currently grabbing all of the records from at once, starting them off as hidden and showing them as the user selects an id (`<xsl:for-each select"">`). The id value is currently being stored as a javascript variable selected by a user clicking that id. 
  I would like to use xQuery to grab the records, but only the records which match the ID the user has selected.  Furthermore I generally understand the logic behind the rules in xQuery i just don't understand how to actually use it in my xsl file.  Is it possible to use xQuery to maybe compare the value of the id(a js variable) to something using xQuery to grab only the records with that matching id?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XQuery is a separate language from XSLT, not one that's embedded within XSLT. So depending on how you are launching XSLT, you can look for a parallel method for launching XQuery. For example, you may try [XQIB](http://www.xqib.org/documentation.php) (I have not tried it, but it looks promising).

If you need more help on that, let us know how you are running an XSLT processor, and what your data source is.

**HOWEVER**... It's not at all clear that XQuery is really what you want. It doesn't sound like you're wanting XQuery for something that you couldn't already do in XSLT. I'm not even sure you're not thinking of jQuery... which is a completely different animal.

It would be helpful if you could tell us more about where the records are coming from; what form they're stored in (an XML DOM?); and what you need to do with them. Probably the best solution then is that we show you how to do what you're trying to do within XSLT (or in Javascript).

### Update

Looking at your new comment, I realize that I may have misunderstood where you are trying to run XQuery. You mentioned javascript above, from which I assumed you wanted to run XQuery in the browser, but now I think I jumped to the wrong conclusion - you are actually wanting to run it on the server maybe?

Regardless of where you're running it, either XSLT or XQuery can select "only the records which match the ID the user has selected". But if the XSLT/XQuery is running on the server, in order for this to work, you have to have either a page refresh or an AJAX call after the user selects an ID, to let the program on the server know what the selected ID is. I'm not sure if you already have that architecture set up, or if you're still trying to figure out how to use an AJAX call to retrieve data based on user input.

It sounds like you want to never send the whole set of records from server to client, not even initially (correct?). In that case, how does the user know what the set of available IDs is?

Anyway, you question may boil down to "How do you run XQuery from ASP.NET?" I have not tried to do that, but this article may help: [Using Saxon.NET in ASP.NET](http://www.pietsieg.com/sections/XQuery/ArtXQueryBeg.aspx); or this one: [Querying XML Data with XQuery](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619192956/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071603-1.2.aspx).

But again, I think XQuery may not be what you want. XQuery is not a querying language used within XSLT - that's more like XPath. XQuery is something you would use *instead* of XSLT, or beside it. So if you're using XSLT and you want to filter records according to what ID the user has selected, assuming you already know what ID the user has selected, the easy way to do that is within XSLT/XPath, rather than firing up a separate processor. E.g. you could say

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//record[@ID = $usersChosenID]"> ...
```

Let me know if this is getting close to a solution for you. There are a variety of directions to expand this explanation, but I don't want to spend time scratching where there's no itch.

Comment: that is true i may be able to do it in regular xslt but all the methods i have tried require me to send over all the data at once using the for each like i had said above.  I am reading in xml from an .aspx page where xml is generated from a database.  I also have an xsl file which I am using to generate the page's html.  I was under the assumption xQuery would just go in the .xsl, but I have never xQuery before or had to query data dynamically in this way either.

Comment: I appreciate the help, and yes it certainly has helped clarify my solution.  But yes i know i have the records update by sending what the user clicked through the querystring to a page utility(sharepoint webpart which is like an iframe) which then brings up the page